# Best algorithm to calculate round values from range

Tags: objective-c, algorithm

I'm doing some chart drawing where on horizontal axis there is time and on vertical axis is price.

Price may range from 0.23487 to 0.8746 or 20.47 to 45.48 or 1.4578 to 1.6859 or 9000 to 12000... you get the idea, any range might be there. Also precision of numbers might differ (but usually is 2 decimal places or 4 decimal places).

Now on the vertical axis I need to show prices but not all of them only some significant levels. I need to show as much significant levels as possible but these levels should not be closer to each other than 30 pixels(.

So if I have chart with data whose prices range from 1.4567 to 1.6789 and chart height is 500 I can show max 16 significant levels. Range of visible prices is 1.6789-1.4567=0.2222. 0.2222/16=0.0138 so I could show levels 1.4716, 1.4854 etc. But I want to round this levels to some significant number e.g. 1.4600, 1.4700, 1.4800... or 1.4580, 1.4590, 1.4600... or 1.4580, 1.4585... etc. So I want to always show as much signigicatn levels as possible depending on how much space I have but always show levels only at some significant values(I'm not saying rounded values as also 20.25 is significant) which are 1, 2, 2.5, 5 and 10 or their multipliers(10, 20, 25... or 100, 200, 250...) or their divisions (0.1, 0.2, 0.25... or 0.0001, 0.0002, 0.00025...)

I got this working actually but I don't like my algorithm at all, it's too long and not elegant. I hope someone can suggest some more elegant and generic way. I'm looking for algorithm I can implement not necessary code. Below is my current alogithm in objective-c. Thanks.

```
-(float) getPriceLineDenominator
{
    NSArray *possVal = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0],
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.5],
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:5.0],
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:10.0],
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:20.0],
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:25.0],
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:50.0],
                        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:100.0],
                        nil];

    float diff = highestPrice-lowestPrice;//range of shown values

    double multiplier = 1;
    if(diff<10)
    {
        while (diff<10) 
        {
            multiplier/=10;
            diff = diff*10;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while (diff>100) 
        {
            multiplier*=10;
            diff = diff/10;
        }
    }

    float result = 0;
    for(NSNumber *n in possVal)
    {
        float f = [n floatValue]*multiplier;
        float x = [self priceY:highestPrice];
        float y = [self priceY:highestPrice-f];
        if((y-x)>=30)//30 is minimum distance between price levels shown
        {
            result = f;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't think I understand the `significant` value part. How do you want to determine what `significant` means?

Comment: Significant I need is number rounded to 1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.2, 0.1. 
OR 10, 5, 2.5, 2, 1
OR 100, 50, 25, 20, 10
OR 0.1, 0.05, 0.0025, 0.002, 0.001
OR 0.001, 0.0005, 0.00025, 0.0002, 0.0001
etc.
depending on what numbers are shown in chart and how much space I have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use logarithms to identify the size of each sub-range.

Let's say you know the minimum and maximum values in your data. You also know how many levels you want.

The difference between the maximum and the minimum divided by the number of levels is (a little) less than the size of each sub-range

```
double diff = highestPrice - lowestPrice;     // range of shown values
double range = diff / levels;                 // size of range
double logrange = log10(range);               // log10
int lograngeint = (int)logrange;              // integer part
double lograngerest = logrange - lograngeint; // fractional part
if (lograngerest < 0) {                       // adjust if negative
    lograngerest += 1;
    lograngeint -= 1;
}

/* now you can increase lograngerest to the boundaries you like */
if (lograngerest < log10(2)) lograngerest = log10(2);
else if (lograngerest < log10(2.5)) lograngerest = log10(2.5);
else if (lograngerest < log10(5)) lograngerest = log10(5);
else lograngerest = /* log10(10) */ 1;

/* and the size of each range is therefore */
return pow(10, lograngeint + lograngerest);
```

The first range starts a little before the minimum value in the data. Use `fmod` to find exactly how much before.

Comment: Some confusion here - 'lograngerest' can never be negative, assuming `(int)` means 'cast to int', 'round to 0', etc. log x increases montonically as x increases. Were you trying to work in rounding as well? In that case, you need to adjust the constants in the second part of your code.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, the available height determines the maximum number of divisions. For the sake of argument, lets avoid magic numbers and say you have `height` pixels available and a minimum spacing of `closest`:

```
int maxDivs = height / closest;
```

Divide the range into this many divisions. You'll most likely get some ugly value but it provides a starting point:

```
double minTickSpacing = diff/maxDivs;
```

You need to step up from this spacing until you reach one of your "significant" values at an appropriate order of magnitude. Rather than looping and dividing/multiplying, you can use some maths functions to find the order:

```
double multiplier = pow(10, -floor(log10(minTickSpacing)));
```

Pick the next spacing up from your `{2, 2.5, 5, 10}` range -- I'm just going to do this with constants and `if`-`else` for simplicity:

```
double scaledSpacing = multiplier * minTickSpacing;
if ( scaledSpacing < 2 ) result = 2;
else if ( scaledSpacing < 2.5 ) result = 2.5;
else if ( scaledSpacing < 5 ) result = 5;
else result = 10;

return result/multiplier;
```

Or something like that. Completely untested, so you'll need to check the signs and ranges and such. And there are bound to be some interesting edge cases. But I *think* it should be in the right ballpark...

Comment: Thanks walkytalky. Isn't this same or very similiar to pmg's solution? I marked his post as an answer because he was first(unless your solution is different).

Comment: @Michal They're pretty similar, yes. I'd have accepted pmg's too :)